# React: Fetch API getting 415 Unsupported Media Type using POST

Tags: json, asp.net-mvc, reactjs, iis, fetch-api

I am trying to save my data through calling my own API by using Fetch API. But then the result is keep coming back `415 Unsupported Media Type`.

Client side is using React JS with .NET Core MVC.
Server side is using .NET Core Web API hosted on Windows Server 2012.

I've tried all the solutions provided in the net but then I still getting 415 error. On the IIS side, I've added `Content-Type` and `Accept` to accept `application/json` and `text/plain`.

So far only GET method works. PUT, POST, DELETE all doesn't work.

Below is my code on the client side.

```
        fetch('https://mywebapi.net/api/event/', {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'Accept': 'application/json, text/plain',
                'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=UTF-8'
            },
            mode: 'no-cors',
            body: JSON.stringify({
                eventId: 5,
                eventName: "Event 5",
                eventDescription: "Event 5 Description",
                eventLocation: "Kuala Lumpur, Malaysia",
                eventDateTime: "2019-03-28"
            }),
        }).then(response => response.text())
            .then(data => console.log(data))    
            .catch(error => console.log("Error detected: " + error))
```

If I remove `mode: 'no-cors'` it would return 500 Internal Server Error instead.

I've tried using .NET using RestSharp and it able to POST normally, but not in ReactJS. So I assumed server side configuration should be correct, but not on client side.

Comment: have you tried it without the `headers` section

Comment: @Priyamal yes, it returns 415 too.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's definitely caused by the combination of `mode: no-cors` and your server's `cors` policy.

By using `mode: no-cors`, the only headers you can use are [simple headers](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#simple-header), aka "CORS-safelisted request-headers", which only consist of `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, `multipart/form-data`, or `text/plain`.

This behaviour is documented [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Request/mode):

> no-cors — Prevents the method from being anything other than HEAD, GET
> or POST, and the headers from being anything other than simple
> headers. If any ServiceWorkers intercept these requests, they may not
> add or override any headers except for those that are simple headers.
> In addition, JavaScript may not access any properties of the resulting
> Response. This ensures that ServiceWorkers do not affect the semantics
> of the Web and prevents security and privacy issues arising from
> leaking data across domains.

So I would:

1. Remove `mode: no-cors` from your request
2. Check your server's allowed origins to ensure that requests from your browser's IP are allowed (for instance, if your react app is running on `http://localhost:3000`, make sure that `http://localhost:3000` is explicitly listed as an allowed origin.

Answer (score 1):

```
fetch('https://mywebapi.net/api/event/', {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'Accept': 'application/json, text/plain',
                'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=UTF-8'
            },
            mode: 'no-cors',
            body: {
                "eventId": 5,
                "eventName": "Event 5",
                "eventDescription": "Event 5 Description",
                "eventLocation": "Kuala Lumpur, Malaysia",
                "eventDateTime": "2019-03-28"
            },
        }).then(response => response.text())
            .then(data => console.log(data))    
            .catch(error => console.log("Error detected: " + error))
```

try it without **stringifying** the **JSON** object, as it will convert it to a **string** you can send the **JSON** object itself without converting it to a string.
BTW I think you don't need to enable **CORS** with each **request** if we **proxy** the requests in the react app. you can enable proxy by adding this line in the package.json file.

```
 ,
  "proxy": "http://localhost:5000"
```

assuming that your backend runs on localhost and on port 5000.

Comment: If I'm not wrong, the usage of `proxy` is meant for development server only, am I correct? No, both of my web client and web API is hosted on production server already and having a valid URL, not localhost. On a side note, the code that you provide throws an error after I remove `JSON. stringfy()`. It says `Types of property 'body' are incompatible. Type '{ <body value> }' is not assignable to type 'string | FormData | Blob | ArrayBufferView | ArrayBuffer | URLSearchParams | ReadableStream<Uint8Array> | null | undefined'.`